# I would like to see if anyone had suggestions when it comes to speed optimization for the site

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, bigcommerce

My current site has horrible optimization. A mobile score of 10 and a desktop score of 60 does anyone have any information on what I can do to make these scores better? Would love some suggestions on what to do. Here is a link to google insights. Thank you to who can help.

https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftouchupdirect.com%2F&form_factor=desktop

https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftouchupdirect.com%2F&form_factor=mobile

[Mobile Score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekeeg.png)
[Desktop Score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myqwh.png)

Answer (score 1):

I personally focus on the Core Web Vitals, which come from real user experiences, and not the PSI scores, which are based on a single simulated test.

I'll audit your home page:

**LCP**

This is the time it takes to show your carousel image. A first improvement would be to do a preload on that image so that it starts loading earlier. And then remove the lazy load from its img tag.

Important images that are above the fold should not be lazy-loaded but eagerly loaded.

Some of your lower-down images are lazy-loaded, which is good. But some are not. In particular, I saw the image in the expandable sections are not lazy-loaded. If you make them lazy-load, they will not get in the way of loading more important resources, like your LCP image.

Your JavaScript bundle is running a few long tasks. This can get in the way of rendering and therefore LCP. Consider looking into reducing or delaying what it is doing. In particular, delay the starting of animations.

**CLS**

Your green selector at the top of the page is added late and pushes down the whole page. This layout shift alone means you fail CLS. Try and pre-allocate the space for it, so nothing shifts.

Comment: Thank you very much I will start trying.